# Regular expression/Wildcard find replace to change date format( 9/7 --> September 7th) in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, wildcards

I am editing a large document that has many dates in mm/dd format.  I would like to change them to "MMMM ddth" format.  I am wanting *9/10* to be changed to *September 10th*. Seems like it should be:

*Find:* `(9/)([0-9]*)( )`

*Replace with:* `September \2`

When I use this, *9/10* is replaced with *Sept10-ember th*.  I also tried:

*Find:* `9/([0-9]*)`<---trailing space

*Replace with:* `September \1th`

...which results in *9/10* being replaced by *Sept10,ember th* - the same, except for the comma.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: (1) I have Word 2007, and I can’t reproduce this. What version of Word are you running? (2) Microsoft Word’s “wildcard” search capability is very similar to command-line wildcards (a.k.a. “globs” on Unix) and ***are not*** regular expressions. In particular, `*` means “any string”, and so `[0-9]*` means a digit followed by anything. Rather than `[0-9]*`, you might want to try `[0-9]{1,2}`.

Comment: (3) Do you have “Show hidden characters” turned on? Are you _sure_ you’re showing us exactly what you’re typing in the Find & Replace dialog box, and what your text is before and after? Because this just doesn’t make any sense. See if you can produce similarly nonsensical results with simpler input; e.g., `[0-9]` [sic] rather than `[0-9]*` or `[0-9]{1,2}` (with text containing a one-digit date, e.g., “9/7”), and then `9/(7)` rather than `9/([0-9])`. I.e., how much do you have to dumb it down before it works correctly?

Comment: @G-Man Thanks for the comments - Hearing that I basically was taking the right approach inspired me to go back to and try to debug some more.  It turns out the problem was caused by having "Track Changes" on.  If I turn that off, then it behaves as I expected.  (Especially after changing * to {1,2})  Thanks,  G-Man

Comment: p.s. I can't upvote your comments because I don't have the reputation to do so on this forum - but I really appreciate the help.  Once I build up some rep, I will come back to this  :-)

Comment: Don't worry about it. But you might want to post an answer describing the solution you found -- it's something I would never have thought to ask about, so it just might be useful to somebody else in the future. However, another one of the limitations of a low-reputation account is that you have to wait a certain number of hours between asking a question and answering it (i.e., answering your own question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comment above, I eventually worked out the problem.  There was an improvement on my regular expression, pointed out to me by G-Man (In order to match two digit days, I should have been using `9/([0-9]{1,2})`.)  That didn't explain the bizarre substitutions I was seeing.

It turns out that Word's wildcard matching find/replace is incompatible with Track Changes.  I turned off track changes, and suddenly everything worked as I expected it to.  This was not user error - it is a bug.

Unfortunately that meant my changes were no longer being tracked.  Since these changes were fairly easy to document in a comment, this was not a huge problem.  In some cases, though, one absolutely needs to have every change noted.  I found a link that describes a method for doing so that is compatible with regular expressions.  I think it would only work if you are the first person to edit a document, though: [blog post from someone dealing with a similar issue](http://www.betalogue.com/2012/06/15/word2011-grep/)